# django i18n_patterns hide default lang_code from url

Tags: django, url, internationalization, url-routing

I'm using the i18n_patterns to add a prefix of current lang_code to my url.

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('blaszczakphoto2.gallery.urls')),
)
```

It allowes me to get urls like `/en/about-us/` , `/pl/about-us/` etc..
My default language is `pl`

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'
```

I want url like /about-us/ for clients viewing my site in polish lenguage. Is there any way to hide lang_code prefix from url for default lang_code?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this yet? I'd love to know it too!

Answer (score 7):

Django `>=1.10` can handle this natively. There is a new `prefix_default_language` argument in `i18n_patterns` function.

> Setting `prefix_default_language` to `False` removes the prefix from
>   the default language (`LANGUAGE_CODE`). This can be useful when adding
>   translations to existing site so that the current URLs won’t change.

*Source:* https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns

Example:

```
# Main urls.py:
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('my_app.urls', namespace='my_app')), 
    prefix_default_language=False
)

# my_app.urls.py:
url(r'^contact-us/$', ...),

# settings:
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en' # Default language without prefix

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('cs', _('Czech')),
)
```

The response of `example.com/contact-us/` will be in English and `example.com/cs/contact-us/` in Czech.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple package: [django-solid-i18n-urls](https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls)

After setup, urls without language prefix will always use default language, that is specified in `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`. Redirects will not occur.

If url will have language prefix, then this language will be used.

Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580467/821594.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem and solved this way:

- Created an alternative `i18n_patterns` that do not prefix the site main language (defined in `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`).
- Created an alternative middleware that only uses the URL prefixes language to activate the current language.

I didn't see any side-effect using this technique.

The code:

```
# coding: utf-8
"""
Cauê Thenório - cauelt(at)gmail.com

This snippet makes Django do not create URL languages prefix (i.e. /en/)
for the default language (settings.LANGUAGE_CODE).

It also provides a middleware that activates the language based only on the URL.
This middleware ignores user session data, cookie and 'Accept-Language' HTTP header.

Your urls will be like:

In your default language (english in example):

    /contact
    /news
    /articles

In another languages (portuguese in example):

    /pt/contato
    /pt/noticias
    /pt/artigos

To use it, use the 'simple_i18n_patterns' instead the 'i18n_patterns'
in your urls.py:

    from this_sinppet import simple_i18n_patterns as i18n_patterns

And use the 'SimpleLocaleMiddleware' instead the Django's 'LocaleMiddleware'
in your settings.py:

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
        'this_snippet.SimpleLocaleMiddleware'
    ...
    )

Works on Django >=1.4
"""

import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.core.urlresolvers import LocaleRegexURLResolver
from django.middleware.locale import LocaleMiddleware
from django.utils.translation import get_language, get_language_from_path
from django.utils import translation


class SimpleLocaleMiddleware(LocaleMiddleware):

    def process_request(self, request):

        if self.is_language_prefix_patterns_used():
            lang_code = (get_language_from_path(request.path_info) or
                         settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

            translation.activate(lang_code)
            request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()


class NoPrefixLocaleRegexURLResolver(LocaleRegexURLResolver):

    @property
    def regex(self):
        language_code = get_language()

        if language_code not in self._regex_dict:
            regex_compiled = (re.compile('', re.UNICODE)
                              if language_code == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
                              else re.compile('^%s/' % language_code, re.UNICODE))

            self._regex_dict[language_code] = regex_compiled
        return self._regex_dict[language_code]


def simple_i18n_patterns(prefix, *args):
    """
    Adds the language code prefix to every URL pattern within this
    function, when the language not is the main language.
    This may only be used in the root URLconf, not in an included URLconf.

    """
    pattern_list = patterns(prefix, *args)
    if not settings.USE_I18N:
        return pattern_list
    return [NoPrefixLocaleRegexURLResolver(pattern_list)]
```

The code above is available on:
https://gist.github.com/cauethenorio/4948177

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [yawd-translations](https://github.com/yawd/yawd-translations) which does exactly that. If you don't care about the extra functionality (manage languages from db), you can have a look at the `urls.translation_patterns` method and the `middleware.TranslationMiddleware` to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

Create django middleware: django_app/lib/middleware/locale.py

```
from django.utils import translation

    class SwitchLanguageMiddleware(object):

        def process_request(self, request):
            lang = request.GET.get('lang', '')

            if lang:
                translation.activate(lang)
                request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()

        def process_response(self, request, response):
            request.session['django_language'] = translation.get_language()
            if 'Content-Language' not in response:
                response['Content-Language'] = translation.get_language()
            translation.deactivate()

            return response
```

It's read the get parameter of request and if it has lang attribute, then switching language. Ex.: /about-us/?lang=pl

Include this middleware to settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    'django_app.libs.middleware.locale.SwitchLanguageMiddleware',
)
```