# Don't show language code for default language in URL of Django CMS site

Tags: django-cms

When I set up a multilingual DjangoCMS powered website the default language code is appended to the URL:

```
http://mypage.com/ -> http://mypage.com/en
```

I don't want this to be the case for the default language (e.g. 'en') Instead what I want is the default language being chosen when there's no language identifier within the URL:

```
http://mypage.com -> Choose English
http://mypage.com/fr -> Choose French
http://mypage.com/it -> Choose Italian
```

How can this be done?

Versions:

- Django CMS 3.0.3
- Django 1.6.5
- Python 2.7

Comment: what version of django-cms are you using ?

Comment: Version 3.0.3, sorry for not adding that initially.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/czpython/1d6ba713c7c0e11ddb0b) for a project that's currently using it in production, they use `django-cms` 2.4.3 but I don't see why it would not work on 3.0, all you need to do is create `middleware.py` file in one of your apps, say `core` and then replace django's locale middleware with the path to this one, since it's a subclass of it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation for a web site based Django CMS version 3.4.5 and Django version 1.8.18. At first sight this seems to be a Django CMS concern, but later I realized this is more related with core Django, which has been natively addressed by the recent versions of this project.

### A working solution

The straightforward solution I applied involved these changes:

1. Upgrade to Django version 1.11.8 (any version >= 1.10 should work). A shell command like `pip install Django==1.11.8 --upgrade` can achieve this.
2. Edit the `urls.py` file to change it like the following:

Original content of `urls.py` file:

```
 urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
     url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
 )
```

New content of `urls.py` file:

```
 urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
     url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
     prefix_default_language=False
 )
```

3. Apply Django migrations, which are part of the new version of Django
4. Run again the Django project and visually verify the new desired behavior

I should mention that someone with the nick `FalseID` at the #django-cms IRC channel gave me the advice to find this solution, as well as other related tips.

### Other references

- Existing answer that applies to a general Django project https://stackoverflow.com/a/43911714/6693126 if the version of Django is >= 1.10. This describes a similar situation to mine.
- For Django versions < 1.10, this answer is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517000/6693126 which is based on the [django-solid-i18n-urls package](https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls). I have not tested this procedure, but it should work.